Is there any Ubuntu program that does speech to text?
I need something that can be installed by ubuntu. I don't know how to make my own source code program and that seems to be everything i can find online. I don't need something that uses a browser either. Please include a "sudo apt-get install" command in any answer, as anything else is far too complicated, especially since typing is a problem. I'm fine with installing the ppa for it if needed, as long as a command for that is given as well. I really need a cut and paste way to install something via terminal.

A bit of Googling told me sudo apt install julius should give you some tools for speech to text. Here is the man page I have never used it, so YMMV.

There are a few questions and answers  on this site about this already - eg https://askubuntu.com/questions/5495/speech-recognition-api    To be honest, I’ve never found anything very satisfactory.

julius installed but i can't find any way to make it run. the main page was all confusing to me.

You may try OpenAI's Whisper: https://github.com/openai/whisper
This is an AI model for speech recognition that uses Python. Of course, you need Python and pip installed in your system, and simply install Whisper with:
pip install -U openai-whisper

It is very easy to use and quite powerful. The github page provides the basic steps for using it.
Note that if you are in an Ubuntu version higher than 22, you will not be able to install PyPI modules system-wide using pip. You must create a Python virtual environment and install all the Python modules within that environment, as well as running Whisper within the environment.

my computer doesn't like the version of pip it's got. I'll have to wait till my proper computer is back from repairs to try it.

what do you mean by 'the computer doesn't like the version of pip'?
